# Combining mclapply and register DoMC in a function

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-caret

I am running a function that utilizes the functions biganalytics::bigkmeans and xgboost (through Caret). Both of these support parallel processing if it is registered first by doing registerDoMC(cores = 4). However, to utilize the power of the 64 core machine I have access to without adding too much parallel overhead, I want to a run the following function in 16 instances (total of 64 processes.

```
example = function (x) {
biganalytics:: bigkmeans (matrix(rnorm(10*5,1000,1),ncol=500))
mod <- train(Class ~ ., data = df , 
               method = "xgbTree", tuneLength = 50,
               trControl = trainControl(search = "random"))
}

set.seed(1)
dat1 <- twoClassSim(1000)
dat2 <- twoClassSim(1001)
dat3 <- twoClassSim(1002)
dat4 <- twoClassSim(1003)

list <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4)

mclapply(list, example, mc.cores = 16).
```

It is important that I stick to mclapply because I need a shared memory parallel backend so that I don't run out of ram in my actual use of data sets over 50gb.

My question is, where would I do registerDoMC in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nested parallelism isn't often a good idea, but if the outer loop has many fewer iterations than cores, it might be.

You can load `doMC` and call `registerDoMC` inside the foreach loop to prepare the workers to call `train`. But note that it doesn't make sense to call `mclapply` with more workers than tasks, otherwise some of the workers won't have any work to do.

You could do something like this:

```
example <- function (dat, nw) {
  library(doMC)
  registerDoMC(nw)
  # call train function on dat...
}

# This assumes that length(datlist) is much less than ncores
ncores <- 64
m <- length(datlist)
nw <- ncores %/% m
mclapply(datlist, example, nw, mc.cores=m)
```

If `length(datlist)` is 4, then each "train" task will use 16 workers. You can certainly use fewer workers per "train" task, but you probably shouldn't use more.

Comment: If I have a list of over 64 items (say 128), but I still wanted to dedicate 16 cores to each train function, would it work to set `m=4` and `nw=16`? Would this effectively run 4 train, then as one finishes, work on the next one in `datlist` until it finishes all 128 - using 16 cores for all train functions? Thanks!

Comment: @KeshavM Yes, that would be fine. It would result in 4 workers that would call train repeatedly until they had worked their way through `datlist`.

Comment: Considering you are the author of many parallel implementations in R, I thought I would ask if you would recommend any other shared memory implementations for this kind of function. As mentioned in my question, my input dataset is around 50gb, so I need a way that it is using shared memory. Thanks!

Comment: @KeshavM The Rdsm package by Norm Matloff might meet your requirements, but I have never used it. You could also consider combining the bigmemory package with doMC. I believe that bigmemory includes features to make it work with foreach/doMC.